# Перемещение по input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Можно ли как то перемещать курсор при вводе данных через `input()`?
Если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, альтернативный вариант `input()`.

`s = input('Строка: ')`

Результат: "Строка: blablabla^[[D^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[A^[[D^[[B^[[C^[[A
"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что значит "перемещать"?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8, как в терминале Linux/Windows/OSX или как по тексту в любом редакторе

Comment: Так это и так возможно.

Comment: "blablabla^[[D^[[C^[[A^[[B" - что то типа такого вижу в XFCE и Gnome терминалах

Comment: Приведите полный воспроизводимый пример. У меня всё редактируется как надо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, добавил всё, что смог, как еще объяснить я не знаю

Comment: В каком окружении запускается Питон? Какие кнопки нажимаются? Это консоль, терминал, SSH?

Comment: Окружение - XFCE
Да, терминал - xfce4-terminal
Кнопки: стрелка вправо/влево/вниз/вверх

Comment: `import readline` в начале программы допишите, возможно?

Comment: Спасибо огромное Вам, помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Установите библиотеку:

```
pip install Inline-input
```

Простой пример:

```
import inline #Импортируем библиотеку
input = inline.input #Заменяем стандартный input

s = input("Строка: ")
```

Вы можете перемещать курсор с помощью стрелочек на клавиатуре, или с помощью кнопок Home, End, PageUp, PageDown

Эта библиотека так же поддерживает автодополнение, ограничения по длине текста и ещё многое другое : )